# Object not a function error

Tags: c#, javascript, forms, visual-studio, button

I am trying to call a javascript modal that says 'no units selected' if the user clicks a 'remove' button without clicking at least one checkbox next to a unit on a webpage. If no units are present, and the user clicks the 'remove' button, the script successfully executes and the 'not units selected' modal appears. However, if units are present, an error is thrown and occurs at the sixth line of the script (if (document.units('Select...etc) ) ). The error states the object (in this case, units) is not a function.

The script:

```
<SCRIPT>
function CheckTheForm()
{
    var found = false;
    var PersonsIDs = "";
    for (i=1;i<=document.units.add_counter.value;i++)
        if (document.units('SelectUnit' + i).checked == true)
        {
            if (PersonsIDs != "")
                    PersonsIDs += ",";
            = PersonsIDs += document.units('SelectUnit' + i).value;
            document.units.action = "UnitsRemove.asp?ID=" + PersonsIDs + "&RA=Units.asp";
            found = true;
        }
    if (found==false)
    {   
        alert("No units have been selected.");
        return false;
    }
    //alert(document.units.action);
}
</SCRIPT>
```

The form that calls the script:

The button pressed to remove the units:

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it says it's not a function, it's probably not a function, and a few lines later you're using it as an object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to do this

```
document.units['SelectUnit' + i].checked
```

which is how you'd access an objects properties with a dynamic key